# Writing an array to an Excel cell from LotusScript

Tags: excel, lotusscript

I have an array that I need to display in an Excel cell

The array is something simple like this

```
gn[0] = "1111"
gn[1] = "2222"
gn[2] = "3333"
gn[3] = "4444"
```

and so on

I cannot figure out the syntax that I need to use to add it to the sheet so that it shows each element on a separate line within the cell

```
xlsheet.Cells(2,22).Value = ???
```

This cannot be that difficult, but it is the Friday after the New Year holiday and for some reason I cannot see what I am missing :)

Comment: You cannot put an array in a single cell.  You will either need to join the values into one string or put the values into many cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my thinking and created a string instead of using an array. I simply appended the variables to each other using Chr(10) & Chr(13) between them.

Problem solved. Sometimes the easy way is the one you think of last.